# Jquery Datatables conflict with Prototype

Tags: jquery, datatable, prototypejs

I am using jquery datatables to load a table. To preface this,  I need to have prototype loaded for mini-cart application. I am putting my jquery into no-conflict mode with this following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
    $j(document).ready(function() {
        $j('#warranty_claim').DataTable({"bFilter": true});
    });
</script>
```

I get the following console errors:

```
  (anonymous function) (index):4747
  (anonymous function) jquery-1.2.6.min_noConflict.min.js:27
  (anonymous function) jquery-1.2.6.min_noConflict.min.js:27
  jQuery.extend.each   jquery-1.2.6.min_noConflict.min.js:21
  jQuery.extend.ready  jquery-1.2.6.min_noConflict.min.js:27
```

However I know my jquery works when I perform this quick test:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
     $j(document).ready(function() {
        $j("#foo").show();
    });
</script>
```

Any help to getting the datatable working would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a possibility that the datatables plugin was not written with no-conflict in mind. So if you need to use the plugin you should be able to easily wrap the plugin source code in a closure to fix it.

```
(function($){
  /* Rest of plugin source here
   *
   *
   *
   *
   */
}(jQuery))
```

And actually looking at the datatables source code it looks like you can just modify the outermost closure

near the top of the code

```
(/** @lends <global> */function( window, document, undefined ) {
```

becomes

```
(/** @lends <global> */function( window, document, $, undefined ) {
```

and

```
}(window, document));
```

becomes

```
}(window, document, jQuery));
```

try that out and see what happens

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that the datatables.min.js you use doesn't have jQuery included.

> Many pages will already have jQuery included, in which case you do not want to include it again. 
>   [Download Builder](https://datatables.net/download/index#Download-builder)

Comment: Finally a solution for my case. When I include datatables.min.js several others plugins crashed. Thanks.